# How to select a string of variable length but with fixed beginning and ending?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I have many strings like `statt 29,95 â‚¬ nur 26,95â‚¬8)  statt 39,95 â‚¬ nur 35,95â‚¬13)` I want to select & remove part which is coming between `statt 29,95 â‚¬ nur`.

String will always start with `statt` and end with `nur` and wil contain some variable length price value in between them. I want them to be removed from my data and contain price values coming after `nur` only.

I looked into the possibility of regex but could not devise a method to use it in my case. Please help me in resolving this issue and pardon my ignorance as I am new to programming.

Comment: Just a hint: Your language seems to be german, so you might want to have a look at the german language [Python Forum](http://www.python-forum.de).

Comment: This string is in German but I am not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all occurences of

```
"statt 29,95 â‚¬ nur "
```

with different prices in "€,cents", you can use this regex:

```
text = re.sub(r'statt \d+,\d+ â‚¬ nur ', '', text)
```

Also, check your encoding, since the characters after the price do not appear naturally.